# Jquery replacewith not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a table that contains a column with a button. When this button is clicked, it toggles the class of the current table row and then replaces the button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".checkOut").click(function() {
        var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
        $(currentRow).removeClass("checkedIn");
        $(currentRow).addClass("checkedOut");
        $(this).replaceWith('<button title="Check In" class="checkIn" value="true" name="check_in"><img alt="Check In" src="../images/check.png"></button>');
    } );

    $(".checkIn").click(function() {
        var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
        $(currentRow).removeClass("checkedOut");
        $(currentRow).addClass("checkedIn");
        $(this).replaceWith('<button title="Check Out" class="checkOut" value="true" name="check_out"><img alt="Check Out" src="../images/minus.png"></button>');
    } );

});
```

The initial click seems to work just fine. However when I click to change the state back to its orignal, it does not seem to work. I think it is a problem with replaceWith. Any help would be most appreciated!

Comment: can you add some html or make an example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".checkOut").live('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $currentRow = $this.closest("tr");
        $currentRow
            .removeClass("checkedIn")
            .addClass("checkedOut");
        $this.replaceWith('<button title="Check In" class="checkIn" value="true" name="check_in"><img alt="Check In" src="../images/check.png"></button>');
    });

    $(".checkIn").live('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $currentRow = $this.closest("tr");
        $currentRow
            .removeClass("checkedOut")
            .addClass("checkedIn");
        $this.replaceWith('<button title="Check Out" class="checkOut" value="true" name="check_out"><img alt="Check Out" src="../images/minus.png"></button>');
    });
});
```

1. You have to use [**`.live()`**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.

2. You were doing an unnecessary re-constructing of the variable `currentRow`. I added a `$` sign, so you know it's already a jQuery object, and not to re-construct it.

In addition, I added code to cache the `$currentRow` and `$this` objects, so you won't have to lookup the DOM every time you want to manipulate them.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're adding the Check In button dynamically (when you click the Check Out button), your click event listener is not going to be attached to it. You could use `live` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".checkOut").live("click", function() {
        //Your event handler code
    });

    $(".checkIn").live("click", function() {
        //Your event handler code
    });
}
```

You will need to use `live` for both, because after the first replacement, a new `.checkOut` element is dynamically added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of replacing you can just change the attribute values which will preserve the event handlers you attached to buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".checkOut").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("checkedIn").addClass("checkedOut");
        $(this)
         .attr({ title: "Check In", class: "checkIn", value: "true", name: "check_in" })
         .find("img").attr({ src: "../images/check.png", alt: "Check In" });
    } );

    $(".checkIn").click(function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("checkedOut").addClass("checkedIn");
        $(this)
         .attr({ title: "Check Out", class: "checkOut", value: "true", name: "check_out" })
         .find("img").attr({ src: "../images/minus.png", alt: "Check Out" });
    } );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

an alternative to existing answers would be one handler for both check in and check out:

```
$(".checkIn, .checkOut").live('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $currentRow = $this.closest("tr"),
            checking = $this.hasClass("checkIn"),
            classToAdd = ckecking ? "checkedOut" : "checkedIn",
            classToRemove = ckecking ? "checkedIn" : "checkedOut",
            buttonTitle = checking ? "Check Out" : "Check In",
            buttonName = checking ? "check_out" : "check_in",
            imgSrc = checking ? "minus" : "check";

        $currentRow.removeClass(classToRemove) .addClass(classToAdd);
        $this.replaceWith('<button title="'+buttonTitle+'" class="'+classToAdd+'" value="true" name="'+buttonName+'"><img alt="'+buttonTitle+'" src="../images/'+imgSrc+'.png"></button>');

    } );
```